# Replacing four letter words of a string with a specific word

Tags: java, string, replace

I am new to string arrays and have a question about replacing four letter words with a specific word in a sentence. For example, I get a string as an input like

```
Being good to them, always helps!
```

replace the four letter words with the word `love` for instance which will be

```
Being love to love, always helps!
```

How can I split all the four letter words of a sentence and then put it into an string array and do the rest?

Answer (score 2):

Use `String.replaceAll` with the following regexp to find 4-letter words: `"\b\w{4}\b"`:

```java
String sentence =  "Being good to them, always helps!";

String fixed = sentence.replaceAll("\\b\\w{4}\\b", "love");

System.out.println(fixed);
```

Output

```
Being love to love, always helps!
```

This allows to get the result string without creating lots of intermediate string and their array.

---

If it is *really* needed to have such array after the split, replace the words in this array, and then rebuild the result string, this can be done as follows.

Also, in the code below another character class `"\p{L}{4}"` is used to match 4-letter words consisting of *only letters* including non-English letters.  (The above-used class `\w` is a shortcut for digits, underscore, and English letters, `[A-Za-z0-9_]`)

```java
String sentence = sentence = "1234 is not a word.    Neither A_Z1. O'Neil in New-York. Орут коты.";
String[] parts = sentence.split("\\b");
for (int i = 0; i < parts.length; i++) {
    if (parts[i].matches("\\p{L}{4}")) {
        parts[i] = "love";
    }
}
System.out.println(String.join("", parts));
```

Output (4-char spaces are not replaced as opposed to 4-digit number):

```
1234 is not a love.    Neither A_Z1. O'love in New-love. love love.
```

---

Also, the replacement and retrieval of the result can be implemented using Stream API when the `Stream<String>` can be obtained from [`Pattern::splitAsStream`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html#splitAsStream-java.lang.CharSequence-) and the result is obtained with `Collectors.joining`:

```java
String str = Pattern.compile("\\b").splitAsStream(sentence) // Stream<String>
    .map(s -> s.matches("\\w{4}") ? "love" : s)
    .collect(Collectors.joining(""));
    
System.out.println(str);
```

Output ("words" with numbers are replaced, unlike non-English words)

```
love is not a love.    Neither love. O'love in New-love. Орут коты.
```

Comment: Thanks, that was helpful. But is there any way to convert the sentence into a string array and then find the four letter words and then replace them. should I use Arraylists or something? I am trying to learn working with arrays.

Comment: I like this answer, it works a treat (and I learned something, thanks!), but it does not use arrays like the OP requested. The original question was more explicit  about wanting to learn about arrays, the current version less so.

Comment: @MikeSlinn, I'm not sure array is really needed for this task.

Comment: You are right. However, OP asked for array for learning purposes.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a program that does what you ask:

```java
String s = "I hate you, you doer"
var array = s.split("\\b");
var list = new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList(array));
while (list.remove(" ")) {};
List<String> result=new ArrayList<String>();
for (String word:list) 
    if (word.length()==4) 
        result.add("love"); 
    else 
        result.add(word);
System.out.println(String.join(" ", result).replace(" , ", ",")
```

Output is:

```
I love you, you love
```

Here is how I figured it out.
I used the Java REPL because it makes exploration easier.
I ignored the comma and pretended it was a letter of a word. If you need to handle punctuation things get messier.

```
$ jshell
|  Welcome to JShell -- Version 11.0.10
|  For an introduction type: /help intro

jshell> String s = "I hate you, you doer"
s ==> "I hate you, you doer"

jshell> var array = s.split("\\b");
array ==> String[9] { "I", " ", "hate", " ", "you", ", ", "you", " ", "doer" }

jshell> for (String word:array) if (word.length()==4) System.out.println(word);
   ...>
hate
doer

jshell> var list = new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList(array));
list ==> [I,  , hate,  , you, , , you,  , doer]

while (list.remove(" ")) {};

jshell> list
list ==> [I, hate, you, , , you, doer]

jshell> List<String> result=new ArrayList<String>();
result ==> []

jshell> for (String word:list) if (word.length()==4) result.add("love"); else result.add(word);
   ...>

jshell> result
result ==> [I, love, you, , , you, love]

jshell> String.join(" ", result).replace(" , ", ",")
$17 ==> "I love you, you love"
```

Comment: Sweet! New for me :)

Comment: I believe this should do it :)

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`String#replaceAll`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#replaceAll(java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String)) method:

```java
String str1 = "Being good to them, always helps!";

// regex groups:
// (^|\\W) - $1 - beginning of a string or a non-word character
// (\w{4}) - $2 - sequence of 4 word characters
// (\W|$)  - $3 - non-word character or end of a string
String str2 = str1.replaceAll("(^|\\W)(\\w{4})(\\W|$)", "$1love$3");

System.out.println(str2);
```

Output:

```
Being love to love, always helps!
```